# Sum the count(*) of between three tables

Tags: sql, impala

I want to sum the number of counts between 3 tables. I have added three input fields to give a specific date each time but I am struggling on how to **SUM** the **COUNTS(*)**

```
select count(*)
from db.table1
where call_date = ${var:call_date};

select count(*)
from db.table2
where call_date = ${var:call_date};

select count(*)
from  db.table3
where call_date= ${var:call_date};
```

thanks in advance

Comment: UNION ALL the selects. SUM() the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` the selects. `SUM()` the result.

```
select sum(cnt) from
(
    select count(*) cnt
    from db.table1
    where call_date = ${var:call_date}
    UNION ALL
    select count(*)
    from db.table2
    where call_date = ${var:call_date}
    UNION ALL
    select count(*)
    from  db.table3
    where call_date= ${var:call_date}
) dt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use them as sub-query as follows:

```
select (select count(*) from db.table1 where call_date = ${var:call_date}) 
+ (select count(*) from db.table2 where call_date = ${var:call_date})
+ (select count(*) from  db.table3 where call_date= ${var:call_date}) 
as rslt;
```